# How can I avoid forEach loops to get data in a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions to send push notification to my users on specific database events, for example when a database entry was created.

I follow these steps:

- Create an `onCreate` method
- Get additional data from other database places to get user informations for example
- Send push notification

For this I wrote the following code:

```
exports.NewEntryNotification = functions.database.ref("entries/{entry}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


    let guestbookID = snapshot.child("guestbookID").val();

    admin.database().ref("guestbooks").orderByChild("id").equalTo(guestbookID).once("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            let guestbookOwnerID = child.child("owner").val();

            admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(guestbookOwnerID).once("value", (snapshot2) => {
                snapshot2.forEach((child2) => {

                    // Token is:
                    let userToken = child2.child("pn_token").val();

                    // If token exists
                    if (userToken) {

                        // Push Notification
                        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
                            notification: {
                                titleLocKey: "new_entry_title",
                                bodyLocKey: "new_entry_desc",
                                badge: "1",
                            }
                        }

                        fcm.sendToDevice(userToken, payload);
                    }
                })
            });
        })
    })
});
```

The problem: My function is processing very very slow. I'm waiting almost 5 minutes until the push notification is sending. I think that I'm using too many loops in my code. But I found no way to get the data in a different way.

Can this be the reason? Or did you find some other mistakes in my code?

Comment: The problem is that you're not dealing with promises correctly.  Your code must return a promise that resolves only after all async work is complete, otherwise it will be shut down early, or behave strangely.  Please read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: In addition to what Doug mentions, the almost 5 minutes is constant? The CF continues running for 5 minutes or it finishes before?

Comment: In the log the function finishes after a few seconds.... but after finishing the main process begins...and the main process runs for 4-5 minutes... strange behavior in the log file...

Comment: Well, is an expected "strange behavior" because as @doug-stevenson mentioned, you're not handling correctly the promises. Could you please try the docs he mentioned?